# Doctrine Entity with fetch="EAGER" causing N+1 queries in dropdown

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, `Client` and `Contact`.  There is a one-to-many relationship between them, Clients have many Contacts.  The association is annotated with `fetch="EAGER"`, and it's reasonable to say that Contact information will always be needed when viewing a Contact (not true in all cases, but a fair generalisation).

However, rather than just always ensuring that only one query is run by automatically joining to Contacts when viewing Clients, I'm observing some behaviour that seems strange to me, specifically when displaying a list of Clients in a Choice field on a form.  Reviewing Doctrine log output, rather than doing a single query and using the results to display a list of Client names, instead a query gets all the Clients and then multiple queries get the data for all the Contacts, one per Contact.  In this case the Contact data is not in fact needed, and I've successfully prevented the behaviour by simply removing `fetch="EAGER".  This seems contrary to the desired behaviour of eager fetching, it's actually having the opposite effect.

**When used to populate a Choice field, why is Contact data not being fetched along with the Client info using a single query as expected?**

I've followed the code through the framework to watch the queries get fired one by one in the Doctrine hydration code, but this hasn't made it clear to me why it's happening.  My pet theory involves something complicated to do with the Choice field "interrupting" what Doctrine would typically do and forcing it to fetch the additional data at a later stage than normal, but I've nothing much to back that up.

*Client form field*

```
$form->add(
    'client',
    'entity',
    [
         'class' => 'AppBundle:Client',
         'choice_label' => 'name',
    ]
);
```

*Client Contact assoc*

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Contact", mappedBy="client", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * */
private $contacts;
```

Comment: I would recommend not to use `featch="EAGAR"`, Collection will be initialized anyway. There are only edge cases when it is necessary to initialize Collection immediately. You may try to replace it with `featch="Lazy"` and it should still give you expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `query_builder` to your `EntityType` filed?

**Example**

```
$form
    ->add('client', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Client::class,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
            return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('this');
        },
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I haven't, but I can have a go.  Why do you think that might have a positive effect?

Comment: It simply allows you to create a custom query for your choices. If default settings causing your problem I would try to specific them.

Comment: OK, thanks, I might try that (although I can't on first glance see why it would make any difference).